# How to extract the footnote from a PDF file

Tags: pdf, nlp, footnotes

[image]

How do I identify and extract the footnote portion of a PDF in Python? especially when part of the footnote jumps to the second page.

I try to use regular expression but there is nothing that i could go off with.

Comment: how about use pdfplumber to find the footnote by it's font size

Comment: really appreciate your help

Comment: yes. sometimes the footnote will continue to the next page and will not leave a number to start with.